# Iterating through capture fields in a Rust regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing, rust

I'm playing around with the frowns parser available from http:// frowns.sourceforge.net, a parser that tokenizes SMILES standard chemical formula strings. Specifically I'm trying to port it to Rust.

The original regex for an "atom" token in the parser looks like this (Python):

```
element_symbols_pattern = \
  r"C[laroudsemf]?|Os?|N[eaibdpos]?|S[icernbmg]?|P[drmtboau]?|"  \
  r"H[eofgas]?|c|n|o|s|p|A[lrsgutcm]|B[eraik]?|Dy|E[urs]|F[erm]?|"  \
  r"G[aed]|I[nr]?|Kr?|L[iaur]|M[gnodt]|R[buhenaf]|T[icebmalh]|" \
  r"U|V|W|Xe|Yb?|Z[nr]|\*"

atom_fields = [
    "raw_atom",
    "open_bracket",
    "weight",
    "element",
    "chiral_count",
    "chiral_named",
    "chiral_symbols",
    "hcount",
    "positive_count",
    "positive_symbols",
    "negative_count",
    "negative_symbols",
    "error_1",
    "error_2",
    "close_bracket",
    "error_3",
    ]

atom = re.compile(r"""
(?P<raw_atom>Cl|Br|[cnospBCNOFPSI]) |  # "raw" means outside of brackets
(
  (?P<open_bracket>\[)                 # Start bracket
  (?P<weight>\d+)?                     # Atomic weight (optional)
  (                                    # valid term or error
   (                                   #   valid term
    (?P<element>""" + element_symbols_pattern + r""")  # element or aromatic
    (                                  # Chirality can be
     (?P<chiral_count>@\d+) |          #   @1 @2 @3 ...
     (?P<chiral_named>                 # or
       @TH[12] |                       #   @TA1 @TA2
       @AL[12] |                       #   @AL1 @AL2
       @SP[123] |                      #   @SP1 @SP2 @SP3
       @TB(1[0-9]?|20?|[3-9]) |        #   @TB{1-20}
       @OH(1[0-9]?|2[0-9]?|30?|[4-9])) | # @OH{1-30}
     (?P<chiral_symbols>@+)            # or @@@@@@@...
    )?                                 # and chirality is optional
    (?P<hcount>H\d*)?                  # Optional hydrogen count
    (                                  # Charges can be
     (?P<positive_count>\+\d+) |       #   +<number>
     (?P<positive_symbols>\++) |       #   +++...  This includes the single '+'
     (?P<negative_count>-\d+)  |       #   -<number>
     (?P<negative_symbols>-+)          #   ---...  including a single '-'
    )?                                 # and are optional
    (?P<error_1>[^\]]+)?               # If there's anything left, it's an error
  ) | (                                # End of parsing stuff in []s, except
    (?P<error_2>[^\]]*)                # If there was an error, we get here
  ))
  ((?P<close_bracket>\])|              # End bracket
   (?P<error_3>$))                     # unexpectedly reached end of string
)
""", re.X)
```

The field list is used to improve the reportability of the regex parser, as well as track parsing errors.

I wrote [something that compiles](https://gitlab.com/araster/frowns_regex) and parses tokens without brackets properly, but something about the inclusion of brackets (such as `[S]` instead of `S`) breaks it. So I've narrowed it down with comments:

```
extern crate regex;
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let atom_fields: Vec<&'static str> = vec![
        "raw_atom",
        "open_bracket",
        "weight",
        "element",
        "chiral_count",
        "chiral_named",
        "chiral_symbols",
        "hcount",
        "positive_count",
        "positive_symbols",
        "negative_count",
        "negative_symbols",
        "error_1",
        "error_2",
        "close_bracket",
        "error_3"
    ];

    const EL_SYMBOLS: &'static str = r#"(?P<element>S?|\*")"#;
      let atom_re_str: &String = &String::from(vec![
//    r"(?P<raw_atom>Cl|Br|[cnospBCNOFPSI])|", // "raw" means outside of brackets
        r"(",
        r"(?P<open_bracket>\[)",                 // Start bracket
//      r"(?P<weight>\d+)?",                     // Atomic weight (optional)
        r"(",                                    // valid term or error
         r"(",                                   // valid term    
          &EL_SYMBOLS,                           // element or aromatic
//       r"(",                                  // Chirality can be
//        r"(?P<chiral_count>@\d+)|",           //   @1 @2 @3 ...    
//        r"(?P<chiral_named>",                 // or
//         r"@TH[12]|",                         //   @TA1 @TA2
//         r"@AL[12]|",                         //   @AL1 @AL2
//         r"@SP[123]|",                        //   @SP1 @SP2 @SP3    
//         r"@TB(1[0-9]?|20?|[3-9])|",          //   @TB{1-20}    
//         r"@OH(1[0-9]?|2[0-9]?|30?|[4-9]))|", //   @OH{1-30}    
//         r"(?P<chiral_symbols>@+)",           // or @@@@....,
//        r")?",                                // and chirality is optional    
//       r"(?P<hcount>H\d*)?",                  // Optional hydrogen count    
//       r"(",                                  // Charges can be    
//        r"(?P<positive_count>\+\d+)|",        //   +<number>    
//        r"(?P<positive_symbols>\++)|",        //   +++...including a single '+'    
//        r"(?P<negative_count>-\d+)|",         //   -<number>    
//        r"(?P<negative_symbols>-+)",          //   ---... including a single '-'
//       r")?",                                 // and are optional    
//      r"(?P<error_1>[^\]]+)?",                // anything left is an error    
        r")",                                  // End of stuff in []s, except    
        r"|((?P<error_2>[^\]]*)",                  // If other error, we get here
        r"))",
        r"((?P<close_bracket>\])|",              // End bracket    
        r"(?P<error_3>$)))"].join(""));          // unexpected end of string

    println!("generated regex: {}", &atom_re_str);
    let atom_re = Regex::new(&atom_re_str).unwrap();

    for cur_char in "[S]".chars() {
        let cur_string = cur_char.to_string();
        println!("cur string: {}", &cur_string);
        let captures = atom_re.captures(&cur_string.as_str()).unwrap();
// if captures.name("atom").is_some() {
//   for cur_field in &atom_fields {
//     let field_capture = captures.name(cur_field);
//     if cur_field.contains("error") {
//       if *cur_field == "error_3" {
//         // TODO replace me with a real error
//         println!("current char: {:?}", &cur_char);
//         panic!("Missing a close bracket (]). Looks like: {}.",
//                field_capture.unwrap());
//       } else {
//         panic!("I don't recognize the character. Looks like: {}.",
//                field_capture.unwrap());
//       }      
//     } else {
//       println!("ok! matched {:?}", &cur_char);
//     }
//   }
// }
  }
}
```

--

You can see that the generated Rust regex works in Debuggex:

```
((?P<open_bracket>\[)(((?P<element>S?|\*"))|((?P<error_2>[^\]]*)))((?P<close_bracket>\])|(?P<error_3>$)))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

(http://debuggex.com/r/7j75Y2F1ph1v9jfL)

If you run the example (https://gitlab.com/araster/frowns_regex), you'll see that the open bracket parses correctly, but the `.captures().unwrap()` dies on the next character 'S'. If I use the complete expression I can parse all kinds of things from the frowns test file, as long as they don't have brackets.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Downvoter: Is there something I can do to improve this question?

Comment: (a) There is a lot of code that is not really relevant to the question; a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be best, but maybe not really possible nor necessary here. (b) Many links could be improved in formatting. (c) There are good reasons why SO prohibits using certain links (e.g. because those links can easily become invalid). It's worth finding out what's wrong with that link and solve this (for example by rehosting the image). --- Haven't seen that you are new to SO, otherwise I would have explained my downvote earlier, sorry! But: welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are iterating on each character of your input string and trying to match the regex on a string composed of a single character. However, this regex is not designed to match individual characters. Indeed, the regex will match `[S]` as a whole.

If you want to be able to find multiple matches in a single string, use [`captures_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.captures_iter) instead of `captures` to iterate on all matches and their respective captures (each match will be a formula, the regex will skip text that doesn't match a formula).

```
for captures in atom_re.captures_iter("[S]") {
    // check the captures of each match
}
```

If you only want to find the first match in a string, then use `captures` on the whole string, rather than on each individual character.